# Save user inputs to database table asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

I am working on a school project where we are supposed to save user inputted data to a database we created within the project. I created a database, called 'db1', in the App_Data folder of my project, and created a table along with it, called 'Video_Games.' My code is somewhat of a Frankenstein's Monster, where it is from examples from my textbook as well as online examples.

```
Protected Sub btnTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTable.Click
    Dim strTitle As String = txtTitle.Text
    Dim strConsole As String = txtConsole.Text
    Dim strYear As String = txtYear.Text
    Dim strESRB As String = txtRating.Text
    Dim strScore As String = txtScore.Text
    Dim strPublisher As String = txtPublisher.Text
    Dim strDeveloper As String = txtDeveloper.Text
    Dim strGenre As String = txtGenre.Text
    Dim strPurchase As String = calDate.SelectedDate.ToString

    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Dim cmdString As String = "INSERT INTO Video_Games(Title, Console, Year, ESRB, Score, Publisher, Developer, Genre, Purchase) 
                                VALUES (@strTitle, @strConsole, @strYear, @strESRB, @strScore, @strPublisher, @strDeveloper, @strGenre, @strPurchase)"


    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db1;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdString, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strTitle", strTitle)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strConsole", strConsole)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strYear", strYear)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strESRB", strESRB)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strScore", strScore)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPublisher", strPublisher)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strDeveloper", strDeveloper)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strGenre", strGenre)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPurchase", strPurchase)

    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Ther error I am getting is from the "conn.Open()" line is:
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Judging by the error, I am assuming that it has to do with my 'conn = New SqlConnection' line, but I cannot find how to make it work. Thank you for any help you are able to give.

Comment: Do you have a SQL Server Express instance named "SQLEXPRESS" on your machine? If you have just copied a connection string from somewhere then it may not be valid for your circumstances.

Comment: This was from my textbook example; it did not give much of an explanation for this so I was not sure how to properly use it.

Comment: How did you connect when you created the database?  You could try using LocalDB, which is installed with recent versions of Visual Studio.  Perhaps something like `conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db1;Integrated Security=True;")` will work (depending on what you have installed/configured on your PC).

Comment: I just right-clicked on the App_Data folder, went to Add, then SQL Server Database. That was what I found online on how to add a database to the project. I tried the LocalDB line, and it still does not want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, took a completely different direction actually; I went the Access database rout instead of SQL. Thank you all for aiding and providing support. The code I used was:

```
Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim strTitle As String = txtTitle.Text
    Dim strConsole As String = txtConsole.Text
    Dim strYear As String = txtYear.Text
    Dim strESRB As String = txtRating.Text
    Dim strScore As String = txtScore.Text
    Dim strPublisher As String = txtPublisher.Text
    Dim strDeveloper As String = txtDeveloper.Text
    Dim strGenre As String = txtGenre.Text
    Dim strPurchase As String = calDate.SelectedDate.ToString
    Dim strDate As Date = calDate.SelectedDate
    Dim intYear As Integer = CInt(strYear)

    If strDate > Date.Today Then
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error: The selected date must be today or earlier')</script>")
        Else
        lblDisp2.Text = "Data Saved to Database"

        Dim connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db1.accdb"
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO [Video_Games](Title, Console, Year_Released, ESRB, Score, Publisher, Developer, Genre, Purchase) 
                                VALUES (@strTitle, @strConsole, @strYear, @strESRB, @strScore, @strPublisher, @strDeveloper, @strGenre, @strPurchase)"

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connection)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strTitle", strTitle)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strConsole", strConsole)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strYear", strYear)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strESRB", strESRB)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strScore", strScore)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPublisher", strPublisher)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strDeveloper", strDeveloper)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strGenre", strGenre)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPurchase", strPurchase)

        con.Open()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr)
        con.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it connection string from https://www.connectionstrings.com.
You can use trusted connection or standart security. When you mssql installation defined  user logging mixed mode or normal. Mixed mode means using user name and password